# php code to check current date and insert current timestamp into mySQL

Tags: php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $staffID = $_POST['staffID'];

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");

$checkInTime = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
 $today = date('Y-m-d');

require_once('dbconnect.php');

$sqlcheck = "SELECT * FROM StaffAttendacne WHERE StaffID = '$staffID' AND Date ='$today'";

$sql = "INSERT INTO StaffAttendance (StaffID,Date,CheckInTime) VALUES ('$staffID','$today','$checkInTime')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlcheck);
 $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if (isset($check)){
 echo "You have already checked in";
 }else {
 echo"$checkInTime";
 mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }
```

how to write php insert check in time (insert time stamp) into SQL database. Time is when app launch . I have written this block of code but did not work

Comment: What do you mean by **but did not work** ??

Comment: Line 1 looks for the submission of a form. `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){....` is looking for a form to be submitted to this page with a method af POST.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `if (isset($check)){` which will always be true because you ahve defined `$check` just above it therefore your `mysqli_query($con,$sql);` is not running.

You should instead use `if(count($check) > 0)`

Comment: Hi thanks for your repond. But how to get a querry result and compare result with current date?